# About OpenCV Template Match

Tags: c#, opencv, template-matching

I tried to use Template Match on source picture and template and wanted to find the source's direction same as template's. (They are the same item and same size)

I checked source picture's direction by rotate 90, 180, 270 degrees and use above method to find the most similar score to get the direction.

But, I think minMaxLoc() is not appropriate to this case, because they always have the same pixel.

Does anyone have ideas or methods on this case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post sample images/templates? Do you use `matchTemplate`? Be aware that `matchTemplate` is sensitive to rotation and scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **SIFT**, **SURF**, **FREAK** features to get rotation invariant result. SIFT & SURF is very good for rotation & scale invariant feature extraction.